# UITextView in Catalyst, Input Source's character picker panel cover's characters

Tags: uitextview, mac-catalyst

I made a note app. Some user reports me a bug. When typing with Chinese Pinyin input source, character picker panel will covers characters in UITextView.

Xcode 12.4 MacOS 11.2.3

Wrong
[image: Wrong]

Expectant
[image]

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let tv: UITextView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 600, height: 200))
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(tv)
    }

}
```